# Create React App and Git Hub pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, create-react-app

I've never user gh-pages before so I'm pretty confused on how it works. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages) over on the create react app page for how to deploy your app to git hub, however every time I try I get an error:

```
> gh-pages -d build

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myApp_game@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myApp_game@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it.

Comment: Build your `master` branch instead, then copy over the assets to your `gh-pages` branch. `gh-pages` is just a static website, so it just wants your HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has a similar problem its because git is not added to your PATH. I was running npm run deploy from command prompt in windows, when I ran it in the git shell it worked perfectly.